# Is this implication in my solution valid?

Tags: calculus

$\require{color}$

> Given that 
>   $$
> f(x) = \begin{cases}
> \arctan(3x),  & x<0 \\[2ex]
> \ \left(x+\frac32\right)\ln\left(2x+1\right), & x\geq0
> \end{cases}$$
>   find where the function is increasing or decreasing.

**My solution:**

Differentiating gives

### $$
f'(x) = \begin{cases}
\ \frac3{1+9x^2},  & x<0 \\[2ex]
\ \ln\left(2x+1\right)+\frac{2x+3}{2x+1}, & x\geq0
\end{cases}$$

$\circ$ For $x<0:$

$$f'(x)>0\implies\frac3{1+9x^2}>0\implies \{\forall x\in \mathbb{R}\mid \frac3{1+9x^2}>0\}.$$

$\color{red} (?) $ For  $0\leq x<\frac12:$

$$f'(0)=3,\quad f'\left(\frac12\right)=\ln(2)+2,\quad f''(x)=\frac{4x-2}{(1+2x)^2}$$

Since the endpoints of the interval are positive and there aren't any negative minimums in such interval, then we can imply that $f'(x)$ is positive in $0\leq x<\frac12$ and therefore $f(x)$ is increasing. By this, $f(x)$ is increasing

$\circ$ For $x\geq\frac12:$

$$f'\left(\frac12\right)=\ln(2)+2,\quad f''(x)=\frac{4x-2}{(1+2x)^2}>0\implies x\geq\frac12.$$

Since $f''(x)$ is positive for $x>1/2$ then $f'(x)$ is increasing. Knowing that $f'(1/2)$ is positive  implies that $f'(x)$ is always positive in the given interval and therefore $f(x)$ is increasing

**This shows that $f(x)$ is always increasing.**

My questions arises on the $\color{red} (?) $ sections. I am not sure if my implication with the minimums is correct. If not, is there any other way to prove this? I also want to add that I am not allowed to use Newton's Method or any other root approximating methods.

Comment: Why don't you use that $f'(x)>0$ for $x>0$?

Comment: @gammatester I don't understand the hint

Comment: If $f'(x)>0$ then $f$ is increasing.

Comment: Once $x\geq0$, there is no point where your derivative is less than zero (both $\ln(2x+1)$ and $\frac{2x+3}{2x+1}$ are nonnegative for $x\geq0$), so that alone shows the function is increasing.

Comment: @Tyberius I did not notice that both of the functions were positive for $x\geq0$, which makes things very trivial. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $x\ge 0$ you have already computed
$$f'(x) = \ln(2x+1)+\frac{2x+3}{2x+1}$$
and both terms are positive. Therefore $f$ is strictly increasing for $x\ge
 0.$

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

Note that

- $f'(x)\ge 0 \implies f(x)$ is increasing
- $f'(x)> 0 \implies f(x)$ is strictly increasing

and

- $f'(x)\le0 \implies f(x)$ is decreasing
- $f'(x)< 0 \implies f(x)$ is strictly decreasing

Comment: Yes, I knew that. That’s why I’m finding when the derivative of f(x) is positive

Comment: @DMH16 Then you are done!